# how to hide specific post from google search

Tags: posts, search, google

I have a wordpress blog set up on my site, example "blog.domain1.com". I have several categories and write posts under each category. I have one specific category that I don't want google search to show on the results page and also the articles written under this category. I used robots.txt and added this 
Disallow: /category/profiles
Disallow: /category/profiles/feed

But when I search the content of the posts by doing site search, it appears in google results. How do I hide these posts from google? 
I used a plug in to hide these posts on blog.domain1.com home page, search page.

Why I am doing this - 
I have another domain example "domain2.com" where I cannot install wordpress so I decided to use a parsing script that will fetch content from my other domain for the posts written under that one specific category "profiles".

How I am doing this -

I created a custom feed script that will have posts only from specific category "profiles". the url will be like this blog.domain1.com/custom-feed. I use this url on my domain2.com script to show the articles.

Can you please help me to take of hiding these specific posts from google search results so that google doesn't think I have duplicate content. I had to do this way because of restrictions that I cannot install wordpress there. Also, no resource for me to do manual work by just creating a static page with content on my domain2.com. To automate it, I used a parser script and then whenever an article is written on blog.domain1.com, it will appear on this domain2.com.

Please clarify.

regards

Comment: I'm pretty sure (and hopefully someone will correct me) that robots.txt is just a "suggestion" and not a fool-proof way to keep the googlebot out.  It is up to the bot to respect your settings, which is probably not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook into the action `wp_head`, test if you are on the category archive or a single post with that category, and print the [proper `meta` element](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93710):

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_91073_noindex' );

function wpse_91073_noindex()
{
    if ( ( is_singular() && in_category( 'CATEGORY_SLUG' ) ) 
        or is_category( 'CATEGORY_SLUG' )
    )
    {
        print '<meta name="robots" content="noindex">';
    }
}
```

Replace `CATEGORY_SLUG` with the real slug of the category (you can find that in `wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category`).

Comment: Thanks will do this but how this will take care of the Post page doesn't have the category in the url. Sorry, if I am asking something that this function will take care of.

Comment: The URL is not needed for this solution. WordPress will look at the post object(s), not at the URL.

Comment: thanks..i thought google index the site and show it on search results so in that case when google index the site it will automatically catch this post/article right?

Comment: Yes, it will read the `meta` element during the next crawl and _probably_ respect it.

Comment: ok cool, thanks. what is wpse_91073_noindex in the function?

Comment: It is a [prefix](http://nacin.com/2010/05/11/in-wordpress-prefix-everything/) to avoid collisions with other function names in plugins or themes.

Comment: thanks a lot, very helpful! working on adding this function to the script.

Comment: I see the meta tag on the category page and on the posts written under this category. Thanks again!