# Where do I add an action hook & callback in my theme?

Tags: code

Another [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91073/how-to-hide-specific-post-from-google-search) suggests to

> Hook into the action `wp_head`

but I am a newbie and I do not know where I am supposed to add the code provided.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_91073_noindex' );

function wpse_91073_noindex()
{
    if ( ( is_singular() && in_category( 'CATEGORY_SLUG' ) ) 
        or is_category( 'CATEGORY_SLUG' )
    ) {
        print '<meta name="robots" content="noindex">';
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me where to add this code?

Comment: At the end of your theme's `functions.php` file before.

Answer (score 1):

The best place for you is probably going to be in your Theme's functions.php file.  Navigate to /wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/functions.php.  Paste it above/below any of the other code there, making sure to stay between any < ?php or ?> tags.